# Problem about running php test suite and test case using Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I need a php test case and how can i test a php test case using selenium RC. Already i have set up Selenium RC in my computer.Not only that, i need a test suite. What is the purpose of test suite and test case? Is the test suite and test case same thing?

It would be very helpful helpful for me if any one post a solution in the blog as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Recorded test scripts can be than exported to PHP language and with the help of these you can create a library which contains all the functions/tests which has to be performed on the application

Now create the suites for different libraries which will call the functions in the libraries and executes it on application.

Start the Selenium RC using the command “java –jar selenium-server. jar”

On the new command prompt enter the specific directory location of the file and enter “phpunit xyz.php”

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a tools that let you automate visits to a site and test for conditions; mostly presense of text on page or in html controls. The selenium server needs to be running which will enable you to control a browser (firefox by default) to do you automation tasks.

Starting the server could be something like

```
  "javaw.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar"
```

where `javaw.exe` is part of your java runtime, most likely in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\`.

You also have the possibility of installing a [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) as a plugin to firefox which lets you record, edit and playback tests.

The most likely usage would though be to implement tests in a test runner like nunit or a php program. The IDE has export functionality for this.